# Java Swing how to clear a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find an answer to my problem anywhere.

Here is my programme:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Window");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addActionListener(e -> windowPreparation(window));

        panel.add(button);

        window.add(panel);
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void windowPreparation(JFrame window) {
        window.removeAll();
        window.validate();
        window.repaint();
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve: As soon as the button is pressed, the JFrame should be reset (I want to remove that JPanel with that Button) so that I can pass it to another class which then does other things with this JFrame.
So that this class can do this without problems, I would like to clear the JFrame beforehand.
I have just tried it as it is written here in my code, the problem is that it just doesn't work, as soon as I press the button the window just freezes. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use a `CardLayout` which is **designed** for this sort of thing.

Comment: You "basic" problem is, `JFrame` is a compound component.  That is, there are a verity of other components which make it's basic structure.  So `removeAll` is actually removing ALL those other components, which you really don't want to do.  You should, instead, be starting with `getContentPane().removeAll()`.  Having said that, I'd be tempted to simplify the issue and take the frame out of the equation and have a "master container" which you used as the base container.  But without more details, I agree with Andrew, use a `CardLayout` instead

Comment: Yeah I refactored my project with cardLayout and now it all works like butter, thank you :D

Answer (score -1):

Do `window.remove(panel);` instead of `window.removeAll()`:

i.e.:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Window");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        button.addActionListener(e -> windowPreparation(window, panel));

        panel.add(button);

        window.add(panel);
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void windowPreparation(JFrame window, JPanel panel) {
        window.remove(panel);
        window.validate();
        window.repaint();
    }
}
```

I stand to be corrected on why your original solution doesn't work, but I think it's because there are "infrastructure" `Component`s in a `JFrame` which aren't related to the components you have added.